# How to create video with images and different time interval?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am struggling with this command:

**ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 5 -i img_0.jpg -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune stillimage -crf 24 -t 20 $frame_target**

it creates 20 sec video with one image. i need to put more images, so i make this like:

**ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 5 -i img_%d.jpg -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune stillimage -crf 24 -t 20 $frame_target**

but this thing create video of 20 sec but images are changing multiple times. basically i want to divide time interval and every image should show ones only.

Comment: How many input images do you have? How long do you want each image to be displayed?

Comment: I have three images for input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -r 0.5 -b 1800 -i img_%d.jpg -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune stillimage -r 5 -t 22 -y output.mp4
```

here `-r 0.5` changes the image after every two seconds and `-t` makes the video 22 seconds long.

Thanks
Preet

Comment: anyway to do this with variable times?

Comment: I am trying to create a video with multiple images and one single audio file. I want the images to be changed at different times. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This is command:

ffmpeg -r 24 -i frame_%04d.png -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 1 -y video-from-frames.mp4 

and this is how I am calculating rate (kotlin):

val audioDurationSeconds =
            TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toSeconds(VideoUitls.getDuration(audioFilePath.absolutePath))
        val rate: Float = 1f.div(audioDurationSeconds.div(videoMetadata.filePaths.size))

This will spread images to total duration at equal intervals.