# How to create video with images and different time interval using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, slideshow, video-processing

It seems duplicate :
[How to create video with images and different time interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546755/how-to-create-video-with-images-and-different-time-interval)
But it ain't duplicate since the author of the above question has framed the wrong title because the images are displayed for fixed time-interval.

What I want to do is this

1. Image 1 : 5 seconds
2. Image 2-5 : 10 seconds
3. Image 6 : 4 seconds

Please let me know how can I achieve this using ffmpeg. I tried googling but found nothing as such.

Comment: I vote to re-open this question, since I think it's related to software development (video-concerning) and use of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it an option for you to make separate videos with the certain length and finally join them together? `ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.yuv|file2.yuv" -f <format> -c copy out.xxx`

Comment: a few hours ago, I came across the same idea. I'm working on it. Will accept it as a solution once I test it really works.

Comment: I used this : `ffmpeg -loop 1 -shortest -y -i p.jpg -i aa.mp3 -acodec copy -vcodec mjpeg result.avi` and `ffmpeg -loop 1 -shortest -y -i p.jpg -i aa.mp3 -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec libx264 result.avi` but neither of them gave me the result instead they give a video of infinite length in which the audio plays once and the image remains forever.

Comment: I found a solution to the above mentioned problem, I used `-t 13` option to limit the size of the video file produced. Now how to create a slideshow (2nd requirement) ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you - my answer is about the last step, joining all videos to a slideshow. This is also where you would add the audio.

Comment: Different images have different sizes and hence the videos produced have different frame width/height, and on merging them the output file is not proper. I'm using below to concatenate the videos
`ffmpeg -i "concat:1.avi|1075.avi|1.avi" -c copy fin.avi` please help on how to concatenate the videos

Comment: If your videos have different sizes I would either scale or pad each of them when producing the single files. Finally join them. For scaling use the output option `-s WxH` like 720x576 - and for padding `-vf pad=width:height:x:y:color` - read http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html